# Sid's for service accounts in alwayson

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, jobs, service-accounts

When creating new maintenance jobs for an alwayson setup with new service accounts, should we ensure that the sid's on both the nodes should be the same? I created a new login with the new domain service accounts and scheduled Olla Hallengren's scripts. I just wanted to check the sid of the service account  on both the nodes. They are different. Is this something which i should worry about?Thanks!

Comment: Are these windows domain logins or SQL Authentication?  I've never created 2 windows logins [Domain/username] and NOT had the SIDs be identical.  Is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 2):

If they are Windows domain accounts/groups, you shouldn't have to worry about it as they should be identical on both nodes.

The orphaned user issue and SID syncing across both nodes is only applicable to SQL authorization logins.  With SQL authentication, you will have to sync the SIDs as, after a failover, the SIDs wont line up between the server level SID and db level SID.

Comment: Yes I am using a domain service account. This was specifically created to run backup jobs. The job is not able to find the UNC path. I get an error saying "Directory does not exist". I googled about this, and found that the domain service account should have read/write access to the UNC file share.  I am checking with the windows team to see if there are any permission issues. Thank you so much for your quick reply!

Comment: Absolutely, let us know if there's anything else you need!  Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: I have a doubt about log on as a service. When I use an sa account or a domain service account to run agent jobs on SQL Server, the log on as section in services still shows NT\sqlserveragent . Is this the way how things work?